Auth client implementation from interceptor going into an infinite loop until stackoverflow
I'm not very sure what is happening the implementation seems alright at sight. I have created an interceptor
    @Throws(ServletException::class)
    override fun preHandle(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any): Boolean {
        val bearer: String? = req.getHeader("Authorization")
        try {
            val user : User? = authHttpClient.verifyToken(req.getHeader("Authorization"))
            req.setAttribute("user", user)
            return true
        }
        catch (error : TraferrException){
            logger.error { "Error in AuthorizationInterceptor trace - $error" }
            throw error
        }
    }

but randomly for some requests falls into an infinite loop of execution
error log
I tried to recreate this scenario locally but never was successfully able to do so.
I understand I could've created a feign client but I did not know about it back then it's just apart of the roadmap for later stages
I'm currently the running the server on an elastic beanstalk instance with Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.8.1
mentioned above in desc

Please [edit] your question and remove the screenshot. Instead, post all relevant logs as text so we can easily search and copy it.

Also, please add the relevant parts that loop, including where it is called. It looks like it might be some (indirect) recursion.
